# Resize a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7

I have two `UIView`s, say `containerView` and `testView`. Say that the width of the `testView` is bigger than that of the `containerView`. In such case, when I add `testView` as subview to the `containerView`, there comes my problem. The frames of the `testView` goes beyond the bounds of the `containerView`. Here is my code -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 154, 200, 200)];
    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    containerView.clipsToBounds = NO;

    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 100)];
    testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    testView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    testView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    testView.center = CGPointMake(containerView.frame.size.width / 2, containerView.frame.size.height / 2);

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 25, 230, 50)];
    label.text = @"This is a Label to test the size";

    [testView addSubview:label];
    [containerView addSubview:testView];
    [self.view addSubview:containerView];
}
```

Output to this code is -
 [image]

When `containerView.clipsToBounds = YES;`, the output is -
 [image]

But what I exactly need is -
 [image] (Edited image)

When I add a `testView` whose width/height is bigger than its superview- `containerView`, the frame of the `testView`(including children) should be adjusted so that, it fits perfectly inside its superview.

I welcome your ideas..!

Comment: you set every time manual the size of testView?? where are there from?

Comment: i just run the same code you specified and i gave got no problems, i mean the output is what you needed.

Comment: @Bala: I run in Xcode 5.0, iOS7. Does it deal with the version?

Comment: I run the code in xcode 4.2 with iOS6, and i got no problems..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modern way to do this is to create the view, add constraints to the view that establish the relationship to the containing view and then add that view as a subview.

That way you aren't messing about with the frames, and resizing with rotation will be handled for you.

**Edited to add**

Here is some example code to do something similar to what you are asking for

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create the containing view
    UIView *greyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    greyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    greyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:greyView];

    // Create the label to go into the containing view
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    label.text = @"Example Text";

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [greyView addSubview:label];

    NSDictionary *bindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(greyView, label);

    // Set the constraints for the greyView relative to it's superview - to cover completely
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[greyView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:bindings]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[greyView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:bindings]];

    // Set the constraints for the label to be pinned equally with padding
    [greyView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(30)-[label]-(30)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:bindings]];
    [greyView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(30)-[label]-(30)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:bindings]];

}
```

If you want to see it in action and tweak the constraints yourself, I've uploaded a [simple example project](https://bitbucket.org/abizern/autolayoutexample/downloads) that you can use.

Comment: Hi Abizem. Seems I have to achieve it, using constraints only. I have no experience in using constraints. I did tried with some formulas and failed. How can I create the formula for this need?

Comment: I was trying a lot for one day. My result is only a white screen everytime. The frame of containerView and testView becomes zero after adding the contraints.

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the constraints correctly? you need to add constraints for the container view to the superview as well as constraints for the label. Here's a hint - don't use containerView as a name - it has a specific meaning when working with Xcode and Storyboards.

Comment: I am not sure about what I use is correct, as I am new to use Autolayouts.

Comment: @iOS I've added an example and a link to a project you can download.

Comment: Its a great tutorial. I worked on it. It helped me to understand the usage of Autolayouts.

Comment: But by doing so, it reforms the frame of the `testView`. Its like resizing the `testView`. Consider that `testView` is something dynamic and I am passing it as an argument inside the method. I do not know how many subviews it contain. No matter, whatever may be the size of the `testView` and how many subviews it contains. I should make the entire `testView` small and bring it inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set the width of your testView (yellow one) bigger than its container and complain after that it's bigger ? You should just do

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 154, 200, 200)];
[...]
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 100)]; // 180 not 260
[...]
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 25, 150, 50)]; // 150 not 230
```

Or use auto-layout like suggested.